# How does one create a header for ones own file format?

Tags: c, file-format

How does one create a file header in C, so that the file type can be detected when the header is read?

What is the correct way to do this, are there any standards to follow?

I would like to add a small header to my file so the file type can be detected when reading the header.

**Update (if you don't have the hat):**

I want to add a header for my own file format (not a .c or .h file), using C, and I will be using C to read the file, identify it and process it.

Comment: Huh? What "file type" ? You mean as in "It's a text file"?

Comment: I get it now! He's asking how to *use* C to create files with special headers. Which means it's ... Too broad / not a question / Not constructive.

Comment: Is this for your local file system? That's Mac OS, right? On other file systems, file types are often determined by the filename extension.

Comment: @BrianRoach I disagree. When creating new file types, it can often be useful to determine what properties a file must have in order not to be recognised as a different type. Or did you think creating new file types is not something that happens frequently?

Comment: There are no rules about what a file's header must look like.

Comment: @MrLister - you disagree with what? That a vague question with no code nor indication of any research effort shouldn't be closed? I wasn't talking about what he *wants* to do.

Comment: I thought it was clear. I want to create a header for my own file type. I already fill the file with the needed data, I now want to give it a header, so I can identify it when I open it in my program.

Comment: Then please rephrase your question to make this perfectly clear. The C language tag seems to be largely irrelevant to me.

Comment: @BrianRoach Hm, I'd be willing to give the OP the benefit of the doubt. That he doesn't show the resuts of any research, doesn't mean he didn't do any research! And code, well, the code would consist of `fwrite(...)`, right?

Comment: @Bart: Thats true, I tagged it with C because I am using C to create the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just write some custom data at the beginning of your file just like you would store any other data.

For example [PGM format](http://users.wpi.edu/~cfurlong/me-593n/pgmimage.html) specifies that there are dimensions of picture and maximum value stored in first lines:

```
P2
# Shows the word "FEEP" (example from Netpbm main page on PGM)
24 7
15
... picture data continues from here
```

There are no standards that would specify making this kind of header since it is very rare to do such a thing. In case of PGM pictures you wouldn't know dimensions of picture without this header - you would read 12 bytes but you wouldn't know if it's picture 3x4 or 6x2...

Note that this kind of custom data is something that you **have to expect** to be stored at the beginning of the file **when** you are **reading it**. You can make up custom header for your files, but then make sure that people who are going to use your files know it.

Comment: Thanks, you seemed to be the only one who understood my unclear question. I know the freedom is there to write whatever I want for the header, I was wondering if there is any standard way of doing this.

Comment: There are no standards for making headers for files since this header is not different from any other data in your file.

Answer (score 3):

Many file formats start off with a small ASCII code or recognisable number to make it identifiable if it is opened by an editor or hex editor. These are also sometimes called “magic numbers”, or “file signatures”. For example:

1. The first four bytes of a GIF file are `GIF`, followed by a three letter version (`87a` or `89a`).
2. The first two bytes of a zip file are `PK` (the original ZIP file's author's initials)
3. The first six bytes of Apple's binary plist file format are `bplist`

There's a comprehensive list [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html). What usually follows is information about what the file contains, like a table of contents, and then after that your actual data.

## EDIT

It sounds like what you're after is a variable-length header. A variable length header usually starts with the number of items in the header, so for example, if you have 5 items in your file, your header may look like this:

```
HELIUM3
5
Item1 INDEX
Item2 INDEX
Item3 INDEX
Item4 INDEX
Item5 INDEX

< then all the data after that >
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the link too. I was looking for file headers, wasnt much other than .h files.

Comment: On the Table of contents/indexing part, I was wondering how this was handled. If I add data chunks to the file one at a time and index them, storing this index data in the table of contents, where would I start the actual data, because as the table of contents grows, there is a chance of it writing over the actual data.

Comment: Thanks. How do I set the start point of the data if the header could grow and overlap?

Comment: Normally, you calculate the size of the header ahead of time, so for example, if you have 5 items, then you need **x** bytes for the magic number, **y** bytes to store the number of items, **z** bytes *per index*, so the size of the header would be `(x + y + (z * sizeof(index) * 5)`, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You answered all the related questions.  :D